# Cannot find module when it is shown on the intellisense

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, graphql, aws-amplify

I am trying to import mutations, queries and subscriptions according to the amplify documentation provided.

```html
import * as queries from './graphql/queries';
import * as mutations from './graphql/mutations';
import * as subscriptions from './graphql/subscriptions';
```

However, when I actually try to apply it to my project, it gives me error TS2307.

[Image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gChO.png)

Even though it appears on my intellisense as shown by the next image.

[Intellisense able to find the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO0CX.png)

I can't for the life of me figure out why, had googled the error, googled the situation but no clear answer that is able to solve my issue...

edit: My tsconfig file as requested.

```html
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it also giving a compilation error? This could be related to ``tsconfig.json``. Can you share the configuration file?

Comment: please post your tsconfig.json and where is you node_module relative to that tsconfig.

Comment: hi i have added my tsconfig.json file, but i don't really understand what you mean by where is node_module relative to tsconfig